# Fonts convert to web format

Tags: html, fonts, webfonts

I received from client fonts like AndaleMono and Swiss721BT
he treat that doesn't have any web format. His files are without any extension. It works in my operation system but I don't have idea how I can use/convert this fonts for using in browser.

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Comment: use this site to convert. https://onlinefontconverter.com/

Comment: thanks. It's interesting. On my OS font works. But converter show response "failed..."

Comment: the font is installed on your machine, that's why it is working.  You want create the web fonts from the above website by uploading your custom font and upload the fonts to the server, import using css.

Answer (score 0):

You can download and extract font Swiss721BT on : https://www.wfonts.com/font/swis721-bt

And declare TTF in your CSS file

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Swis721";
    src: url('public/fonts/Swis721_Cn_BT_Roman.ttf');
}
```

Do the same with the other one... AndaleMono http://fonts.cooltext.com/Downloader.aspx?ID=11521

Finally, in your code do something like :

```
body {
    font-family: Swis721, AndaleMono;
}
```

Please note : AndaleMono is under Microsoft license related. So make sure, you respect conditions.